# Closing MongoDB connection in findOne callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I'm running the following code, **sometimes** MongoDB will error out saying `Connection was destroyed by application`

Is it ok to `db.close()` immediately in the callback?

```
User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      db.close();
      if (err) {
        console.log('local.js user findone err', err);
        return done(err);
      }

      if (!user)
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
        if (err)
          return done(err);
        if (!res)
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        return done(null, user);
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: No. Why are you doing this? You never close database connections until you are **truly** done with them for good.

Comment: @hoverhand, not sure if you intentionally passed in with null as the 1st argument in one of your callbacks when it's not successful.  Usually, null means successful. if (!res) return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });